Unexpected animation from UICalendarView embedded in UIStackView
I have a UICalendarView that is embedded in a UIStackView. When I hide/show items in the stack and cause the height of the stack to change, the UICalendarView animates unexpectedly:

Note that the height and width of the UICalendarView remain unchanged and the animation appears to leave the actual content unchanged.
Interestingly, if I select a month with 6 weeks it does not do this animation:

Nothing I have tried has allowed me to avoid this distracting and unnecessary animation. Any thoughts as to why this is happening or, even better, is there anything I can do to avoid it?
Appreciate the help!
(also posted on Apple developer forums)

Quick test -- I cannot reproduce the issue. Provide enough code so we can see what's happening: [mre]

Admittedly, I should have done so before even asking but, while preparing an example, I also was not able to reproduce. After a bit of experimentation, I found out that the animation happens when I assign the UICalendarView's selectionBehavior property to an instance of UICalendarSelectionMultiDate (to enable multiple date selection) just before animating the changes to the UIStackView's contents. I'm not sure why that triggers an animation but I was at least able to fix my specific issue by simply assigning the new selectionBehavior in the completion block of my animation.
Thank you!

Turns out the animation happens when I assign the UICalendarView's selectionBehavior property to an instance of UICalendarSelectionMultiDate (to enable multiple date selection) just before animating the changes to the UIStackView's contents. I'm not sure why that triggers an animation but I was at least able to fix my specific issue by simply assigning the new selectionBehavior in the completion block of my animation.
In essence, I changed:
self.calendarView.selectionBehavior = UICalendarSelectionMultiDate(delegate: nil)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
    self.enableMultiDateButton.isHidden = true
    self.enableMultiDateButton.alpha = 0
    self.submitButton.isHidden = false
    self.helpTextLabel.isHidden = false
}

to:
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
    self.enableMultiDateButton.isHidden = true
    self.enableMultiDateButton.alpha = 0
    self.submitButton.isHidden = false
    self.helpTextLabel.isHidden = false
}) {_ in
    self.calendarView.selectionBehavior = UICalendarSelectionMultiDate(delegate: nil)
}

